# Unprotected private ssh key generated by java prompts for passphrase

Tags: java, ssh, rsa, private-key

I'm tying to generate a ssh key pair using Java. For the private key no passphrase has been set. The key is saved as Base64 encoded string to a file.

The problem is that the private key seems to be protected by an passphrase. If I test the key using command `ssh-keygen -y -f <private key file>`, the public key is not displayed instead a passphrase is requested. If I simply hit the enter key, I get the response `load failed`. For private key generated with command `ssh-keygen -f <key file name> -t rsa -b 4096`, no passphrase is required to display the public key.

I've generated the key pair in java like below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(4096);
        
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        String privateKey = generatePrivateKey(keyPair.getPrivate());
        
        saveKeyContent(privateKey);
    }
    
    private static String generatePrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey) {
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        
        String key = encoder.encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded());
        
        
        return String.format("%s%n%s%n%s", "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", key, "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
    }
    
    private static void saveKeyContent(String content) {
        try {
            Path filePath = new File("d:\\tmp\\").toPath().resolve("testKey");
            Files.write(filePath, content.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Does the base64 encoded RSA private key data have newlines? AFAIK the line length has to be exactly 64 characters (except the last) see also this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52127/744

Comment: Maybe the file is in the wrong format. There are a lot of formats, why do you think you chose the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments.

@Robert: Actually correcting the line length to 64 characters solved the issue. I also found out that the problem is related to the version of ssh-keygen. E.G. on Linux Mint 19.x the public key is displayed even with a private key line length > 64 characters. If you use e.g. Redhat 6 the a private key line length > 64 characters is not working.